# How to make a reload viewController always when seen?

Tags: objective-c, viewcontroller

I Have a view that shows Profile Information, But I want always to make a request when the Tab is Tapped. Because it loads it once. I would not like to use a Pull to refresh Feature that's my last option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want `viewWillAppear:`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //reload your view here...
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html